# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Required by: project :app

> No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.

### Error log:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.support:design:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.support:design:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 available for offline mode.

**Error log image:**

[image: Click here for image]

Comment: If you are using a VPN turn it off to get it to work.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Go to `File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.`

Comment: You should invalidate your cache and restart. Follow this steps `file` -> `invalidate caches/Restart` Then select `invalidate and restart` in the dialog box that appears.

Comment: You need to sync the project again.

Comment: I don't find this option available in the Android studo

Comment: @Arefe It has since moved to the dedicated Gradle panel on the right side of the main window where a dedicated "Toggle Offline Mode" button can be clicked.

Comment: for me this option is uncheck but i have this error

Answer (score 36):

Below is a workaround demo image of ; Uncheck <kbd>Offline work</kbd> option by going to:

> <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> -> <kbd>Gradle</kbd>

[image]

## If above workaround not works then try this:

> 1. Open the `build.gradle` file for your application.
> 2. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:
>
>    ```
>    allprojects {
>         repositories {
>             jcenter()
>             maven {
>                 url "https://maven.google.com"
>             }
>         }
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Add the support library to the `dependencies` section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:
>
>    ```
>    dependencies {
>        ...
>        compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0"
>    }
>    ```
>
> **Caution:** Using dynamic dependencies (for example, `palette-v7:23.0.+`) can cause unexpected version updates and regression incompatibilities. We recommend that you explicitly specify a library version (for example, `palette-v7:27.1.0`).
>
> ## Manifest Declaration Changes
>
> Specifically, you should update the `android:minSdkVersion` element of the `<uses-sdk>` tag in the manifest to the new, lower version number, as shown below:
>
> ```
> <uses-sdk
>   android:minSdkVersion="14"
>   android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
> ```
>
> If you are using Gradle build files, the `minSdkVersion` setting in the build file overrides the manifest settings.
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>    ...
>       defaultConfig {
>             minSdkVersion 16
>             ...
>         }
>         ...
>     }
> ```

## Following [Android Developer Library Support](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#using-apis).

Answer (score 16):

Just went to `build.gradle` and deleted the line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

After that, I re-synced the Gradle. Then, I pasted the line of code back, re-synced the Gradle again and it worked.

**Note:** While I was making this changes, I also updated all the SDK Tools that needed update.

Answer (score 8):

### `Invalidate Cache / Restart` from File option.

Just unchecking offline mode did not work for me.

Comment: The option seems unavailable now in the Android studio

Answer (score 7):

In the android\app\build.gradle file,

Replace the version details

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Android Studio will use a suitable version to make it work for you.

Answer (score 6):

use `Invalidate Caches/Restart` it will works for you and make sure that your gradle offline sync option is not enabled

Answer (score 6):

Adding this in project gradle worked for me

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com" // specifically this worked 
     }
 }}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem for users who live in a country that is banned by Google (like Iran).
for this reason we need to remove these restrictions by a proxy.
follow me :

file->settings->Appearance&Behavior->System Setting-> Http Proxy-> Manual proxy configuration ->HTTP -> Host name : fodev.org ->Port : 8118 .

and click Ok Button.
then go to file-> Invalidate Caches/Restart .
.
.
Use and enjoy the correct execution without error ;)

Comment: in iran we use shecan dot iran service ;) do you? i changed my dns and its worked

Comment: shekan  just can open the developers.android and cant open other websites like medician.com and  interanet websites

Answer (score 1):

Today I have the similar problem.

Previous in my project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}}
```

Then I just added this below line in allprojects

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

It saved my day.

And now my current allproject {} code looks like this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup):

> Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to
>   add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     ...
>     implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. In Home Ubuntu, I deleted the **.gradle** folder and downloaded it again.
I hope it is useful

Answer (score 1):

*Go to File->Other Settings->Preferences for New Projects->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.*

Comment: The difference is between this "Default Settings" and this "Preferences for New Projects". I pretty sure you understand now

Answer (score 0):

## For users which have flavors in the project and found this thread:

Notice, that if your module dependency has different flavors, you should use one of the strategies:

1. Module that tightens dependencies should have the same flavors and dimensions as
   the dependency module
2. You should explicitly indicate which configuration you target in the module

Like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':module', configuration:'alphaDebug') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and adding `mavenCentral()` in the repositories block of my build.gradle file worked for me. I had Offline work unchecked and adding `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`. Adding this answer for the lost souls that find themselves at end of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not **uncheck offline work**, then make you sure you have internet for Android Studio to normalize your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this same error after adding dynamic module then don't worry follow this:

- Add productFlavors in your build.gradle(dynamic- module)

  ```
  productFlavors {
  flavorDimensions "default"
  stage {
     // to do
  }
  prod {
     // to do

   }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For other people where the accepted answer does not solve this issue...

As of September 2018, AndroidX has replaced the Android Support Libraries, which includes the appcompat-v7 library.

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' becomes 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

'com.android.support:design' becomes 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

> References:
>
> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
>   List of Support Libraries to AndroidX mappings

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was incorrect url for `jcenter`. To solve it I simply changed url for app and proect level `build.gradle`

from

```
jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
```

to

```
jcenter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.Gradle file and replace 27 and 29 by 25 at these places 
  1. targetSdkVersion 25
  2. implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'

it really works for me 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Used implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.2' in App gradle  fixed the issue for me