# Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. => configure HTTP proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, http-proxy

I downloaded Android Studio 3.0 and I started following along [building my first app tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html). But Gradle threw errors like:

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

I searched on SO for similar problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45103230/3405291) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999594/3405291), but none of them helps me.

---

Eventually I figured out that I'm using a proxy for Android Studio:

[image]

To resolve the error, I have to implement the proxy for Gradle too, by adding these lines to `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost, 127.0.0.1
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118

systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost, 127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
```

After adding the above statements to `gradle.properties`, the error got resolved. Note that **both** `HTTP` and `HTTPS` proxies need to be added to Gradle properties

Comment: thanks a lot bro .. It solved my problem and gradle errors after hours searching for solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error. Tried a lot of stackoverflow links but none of them helped until this one. The problem in my case was due to https proxy settings which were not there in the gradle.properties file. I included it and it worked.

For android studio 3, inside build.gradle file of your project you have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

The jcenter() runs over https and hence if you are building in a network(in most cases company network) which uses https proxy, and you forgot to include it in your gradle.properties file, then you are likely to face the issue. You may feel that gradle is behaving weird but its not. Its only missing the proper network configuration. Even offline build settings wont work since it still needs jcenter() to download files for the first time you are building an app in latest Android Studio.

I included my https proxy settings in gradle.properties like this:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxy server address>
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost, 127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<port number>
```

Comment: What should be as port number?

Comment: The port 8080 is used by the proxy address to connect you to the internet services. Use this:
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080