# Android Studio 3.0.1 gradle build pkix pathbuilding failed

Tags: java, android

I have created a new project in android studio 3.0.1 setup the proxy settings of company and added the self sighned certificate under server certificates. When I try to build the following error is listed and the build fails.

Error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
          > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
                   > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                              > unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124746/could-not-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v726-1-0-configure-http-pro)

Comment: This can not be cause I have set the gradle.properties for proxy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved this by adding the self signed certificate of my company to the cacerts file of Android Studio. The cacerts file is located here: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security\cacerts`

I have also added the proxy details for http/https to gradle.properties.

Comment: how did you do it? and how to get my proxy cert?

Comment: simply add the self sighned certificate of your company to the specified path above or where ever you installed android studio.

Comment: thanks, I thought that `cacerts` is a file not a folder. I will try it

Comment: cacerts is of course a file, simply open (as admin) it with e.g. kestore explorer and add your certificate

Comment: worked for me, Thanks - remember default password to open cacerts file is "changeit" and download link for keystore explorer is - http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html

Comment: @SanjayKumar, where to get the company certificate file and add in downloaded KeyStore Explorer.

Comment: Remember to keep backup copy of the original file, as otherwise the Android Studio update will fail, and you will have to reinstall from full installer.

Answer (score 2):

**lets resolved this issue** so
go to the **stack trace** and see the **first url** of your **stack trace** where issue is pointed like in this post

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
```

in your browser: but before that strip the last `.pom` or `/filename.extension` from your url.

- in chrome - click on site of url icon left(`lock icon` in general) to address in address bar,
- select `"Certificate" -> "Certification Path"->`select root node like `"Corp-Prj-Root-CA"-> "View Certificate" -> "Details" -> "Copy to File..."` and save in the format of `"Der-encoded binary X.509(.CER)"` single certificate file let name it **`rootCertFile.cer`**.
- Now you have file with keystore and you have to add it to your JVM. To Determine location of `cacerts` files eg. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts`.
- or check your android studio Java Path in `Project settings`

Next import the **`rootCertFile.cer`** file into cacerts

> Solution1

using `keytool` in command line (you need to run as administrator command prompt):

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts" -file rootCertFile.cer
```

You will be asked for password by default it is `changeit`

> Solution2

you can use the [keyExplorer software](https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) run as administrator and open the `yourjavapath-> jre->lib->security-> cacerts` file **as per android studio path** in it and

- it will asked for password by default it is  `changeit` enter then
- click on the `"Import Trusted certificate"` icon or from `Tools` option and give the path of above saved certificate name **`rootCertFile.cer`**
- then it will as for `alias name` give **some unique name** and press `ok`  and
- click on the `save icon`
- also make sure about the **proxy setting** if any from **company depend on certificate** then that ***certificate** also we need **to add in same way***
- and we are done `delete android studio caches directory` and now try `gradle sync` in your project

Comment: I am using mac and there is no folder with the name cacerts. what we can do in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have resolved the issue by changing the WiFi network connection. do any of the following step
1. connect to other or Mobile network(use hotspot) and reconnect to WiFi network
2. Reset your wifi network in laptop

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding below script code in root build.gradle under buildscript tag

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://raw.github.com/Raizlabs/maven-releases/master/releases"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

The key is to add

> allowInsecureProtocol = true

Answer (score 0):

lol, I have fixed this issue just by opening second link from error info ***https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android...*** in the Google Chrome. Then it has worked just like always  ¯\ _ (ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to just upgrade to the latest gradle wrapper (gradle-wrapper.properties) and gradle plugin (main build.gradle -> buildscript -> dependencies -> com.android.tools.build:gradle). This is especially true if you're loading multiple projects and you've updated one of them. I did that and suddenly my "other" projects wouldn't sync/build. Updating them as well resolved that issue.

It bears noting that our company does have a very locked down network with tons of traffic sniffing and cert rewriting so that's likely the initial cause of the issue. Even with adding the self-signed certs into Android Studio's "approved" certificate list, I was still having issues until I did the above. Previously, I've even seen a difference between building in the terminal (./gradlew assembleDebug, which worked more often) and building in Android studio (which worked less often).