Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources
I created a brand new empty views activity in Android Studio Ladybug, and the gradle sync fails with:
Build file '/path/to/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/build.gradle.kts' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.resolve.internal.PluginResolutionResult.getFound(PluginResolutionResult.java:112)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequest(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:192)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:97)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.PluginRequestsHandler.handle(PluginRequestsHandler.kt:45)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.applyPluginsTo(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:219)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$ProgramHost.applyPluginsTo(Interpreter.kt:385)
    at Program.execute(Unknown Source)
    ...

I suspect this might have something to do with my work machine vpn blocking something, but the ./gradlew build --debug output doesn't really indicate any issue with hitting dl.google.com, and I can download the https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom from my web browser.
Here is some of the output from ./gradlew build --debug which indicates it looks in maven after google for some reason for the dependency:

2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom' started
2024-11-19T14:22:29.210-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom'
2024-11-19T14:22:29.212-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom' started
2024-11-19T14:22:29.568-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom'
2024-11-19T14:22:29.570-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom' started
2024-11-19T14:22:30.064-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom'
2024-11-19T14:22:28.891-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:28.891-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:28.891-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Opening cache resource-at-url.bin (/Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.106/resource-at-url.bin)
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://dl.google.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 4][route: {s}->https://dl.google.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2024-11-19T14:22:28.894-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://dl.google.com:443
2024-11-19T14:22:28.896-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to dl.google.com/142.250.72.142:443
2024-11-19T14:22:28.896-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to dl.google.com/142.250.72.142:443 with timeout 30000

2024-11-19T14:22:29.209-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 4][route: {s}->https://dl.google.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2024-11-19T14:22:29.211-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:29.212-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:29.212-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:29.212-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:29.213-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom
2024-11-19T14:22:29.213-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
2024-11-19T14:22:29.213-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
2024-11-19T14:22:29.213-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2024-11-19T14:22:29.214-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 5][route: {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total 
2024-11-19T14:22:29.996-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Secure session established
2024-11-19T14:22:29.996-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2024-11-19T14:22:29.996-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
2024-11-19T14:22:29.996-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer principal: CN=repo.maven.apache.org
2024-11-19T14:22:29.996-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  peer alternative names: [repo.maven.apache.org]
2024-11-19T14:22:29.997-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]  issuer principal: CN=GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2024 Q4, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
2024-11-19T14:22:29.997-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established 10.38.67.88:60659<->146.75.80.215:443
2024-11-19T14:22:29.997-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-7: set socket timeout to 30000
2024-11-19T14:22:29.997-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request GET /maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom HTTP/1.1
2024-11-19T14:22:29.997-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2024-11-19T14:22:29.998-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2024-11-19T14:22:30.062-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2024-11-19T14:22:30.063-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection [id: 7][route: {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
2024-11-19T14:22:30.063-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-7: set socket timeout to 0
2024-11-19T14:22:30.063-0600 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 7][route: {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443][total available: 2; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2024-11-19T14:22:30.063-0600 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom]
2024-11-19T14:22:30.064-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResponseResource] Attempting to download resource https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.064-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.7.2/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.7.2.pom' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.064-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.2' in repository 'Gradle Central Plugin Repository'.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.064-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.PersistentModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.2 [changing = false]
2024-11-19T14:22:30.065-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in /Users/myuser/.gradle/.tmp/gradle13329521743190440689.bin. Wrote root 7.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.065-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of detachedConfiguration1' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.065-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Resolve files of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Apply build file 'build.gradle.kts' to root project 'testcompile5'' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 1.395 secs
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Notify afterEvaluate listeners of :' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on state of build :
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Configure project :'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Configure project :' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Configure build'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Configure build' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.066-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Finish root build tree' started
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Finish root build tree'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Finish root build tree' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/build.gradle.kts' line: 2
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.2')
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following repositories:
2024-11-19T14:22:30.068-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     MavenRepo
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     Gradle Central Plugin Repository
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     Google
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 3s
2024-11-19T14:22:30.069-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' started
2024-11-19T14:22:30.070-0600 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.watch.registry.impl.HierarchicalFileWatcherUpdater] Watched directory hierarchies: [/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5]
2024-11-19T14:22:30.070-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.070-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Build finished for file system watching' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.072-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (/Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/8.9/md-supplier)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.072-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (/Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/8.9/md-supplier).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.072-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.072-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.073-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-rule (/Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/8.9/md-rule)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.073-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-rule (/Users/myuser/.gradle/caches/8.9/md-rule).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.073-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.074-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.074-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.0 secs
2024-11-19T14:22:30.074-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.074-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Run build' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.074-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 2: released lock on worker lease
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/fileHashes)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache resourceHashesCache.bin (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/fileHashes/resourceHashesCache.bin)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/fileHashes).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for checksums cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/checksums)
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on checksums cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/checksums).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.077-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCleanupExecutor] VCS Checkout Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/vcs-1) has last been fully cleaned up 0 hours ago
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCleanupExecutor] Skipping cleanup for VCS Checkout Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/vcs-1) as it is not yet due
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator] Cache VCS Checkout Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/vcs-1) was closed 0 times.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator] Cache VCS metadata (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/vcsMetadata) was closed 0 times.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCleanupExecutor] dependencies-accessors (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/dependencies-accessors) has last been fully cleaned up 0 hours ago
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCleanupExecutor] Skipping cleanup for dependencies-accessors (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/dependencies-accessors) as it is not yet due
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator] Cache dependencies-accessors (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/dependencies-accessors) was closed 0 times.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator] Cache Compressed Files Expansion Cache (/Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle/8.9/expanded) was closed 0 times.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Deleting unused version-specific caches in /Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle' started
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Deleting unused version-specific caches in /Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle'
2024-11-19T14:22:30.078-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Deleting unused version-specific caches in /Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/testcompile5/.gradle' completed
2024-11-19T14:22:30.090-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
2024-11-19T14:22:30.107-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
2024-11-19T14:22:30.107-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Success[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildActionResult@4a11eb84] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=33670, address=[95f54f6f-c9d5-4c99-9c83-437c9864b0c8 port:59598, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1732045393676, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e6a7ec55-897c-43fa-96d2-d127dd3e7f0d,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home,javaVersion=17,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/myuser/.gradle/daemon,pid=33670,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,applyInstrumentationAgent=true,nativeServicesMode=ENABLED,daemonOpts=--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
2024-11-19T14:22:30.107-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
2024-11-19T14:22:30.107-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
2024-11-19T14:22:30.109-0600 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction] 
#############################################################################
   WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING

   Debug level logging will leak security sensitive information!

   For more details, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.9/userguide/logging.html#sec:debug_security in the Gradle documentation.
#############################################################################


Here's my settings.gradle.kts:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "testcompile5"
include(":app")



My issue ended up being not having my company's self signed certificate in my JDK's cacerts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68596094/27576792
