# Android Studio 3.0.1. won't sync the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just installed a fresh new Android Studio on a fresh new Windows 7. I created a new empty project and Android Studio keeps failing at project syncing. I tried few solutions people posted on SO, but none of them worked so I decided to show you my project structure hoping someone can help.

So, this is my project's gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And module's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kompjutor.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

}

And those are the errors I'm getting:

[image: Errors]

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Try adding `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` in project level build.gradle under buldscript.repositories and `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in project level build.gradle under allprojects.repositories

Comment: still the same errors.. :/

Comment: do u use any proxies ? it is just sync issue. Go to settings > search proxy or gradle sync and make it run .

Comment: "No proxy" option is selected..  and when I search "Gradle", option "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" is selected

Answer (score 2):

Issue could be caused by the following reasons

1. Gradle has not synced the libraries.
2. Android Studios offline mode is activated.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114291/7702686) for more info

Comment: Any ideas how to fix 1. issue? 2. is not an issue since offline mode is not activated

Answer (score 1):

Go to File->Project Structure.

In the Dependency Tab Choose Plus icon appears green then choose Library dependency. And add through that. If still problem appears update Support Repository through SDK Manager

[image]