# Could not resolve com.android.support:recyclerView-v7:26.1.0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I am using RecyclerView for that I have added the dependency file in the Gradle after that I can't run my project because of the error I have put in the title.

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nemuees.www.reminder"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerView-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'

}
```

And I have referred some SO post regarding this error and put this in my build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have Unchecked the **offline Work** in Gradle Settings

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and manually delete the `build` folders under the project folder and under `app`?

Answer (score 0):

May be because you forgot to add `buildToolsVersion`.

Like

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
```

Also it seems looking design `dependency` added twice so remove that define it once only.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```