# I am getting an error on appcompat in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Iam using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I am getting an Error.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app

> No cached version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 available for offline mode.

Comment: uncheck offline work option in gradlr

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114291/7910735

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)