# Error adding Design Library

Tags: android

I am fresher in developing Android Apps.
I need a tabbed layout and added Design library for tabbed layout in my Android project.
I get several errors with a common description as below.

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0.

Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
Required by:
project :app
> Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.1.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/design/26.1.0/design-26.1.0.pom'.
      > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/design/26.1.0/design-26.1.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                           > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                          > unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.naari.simpleApp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Project:AndroProject

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What should I do to fix it?
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv) link, but it did not fix.
I have no certificates under Settings-->Server certificates.
Any thoughts?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103230/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportcardview-v726-0-0-android

Comment: I already have `google()` which does the same thing as `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }`.  It did not work.

Comment: What´s your java version?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_31"

Comment: add this and see if it works = implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: also make sure that your internet is connected when your gradle is syncing.