# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Note.** 
This not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question but the extension as there are few more error I got and the solution in that question stated was not solving my errors.

**Problem:** 
Recently I am migrating my older project to upper version. I have updated Android Studio to 3.1 and Using API 27 with Gradle 4.4. I have changed the depricated `compile` to `implementation` now I am facing a very weird error. I am telling weird as I have tried many solution stated in other question and answers but nothing helped me. Beside the `:app@debug/compileClasspath` I am getting also the following errors

```
:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath
:app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath
:app@release/compileClasspath
:app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath
```

I think all errors are related. I am getting this long list of error with every libraries.

Here is my app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.epp.app.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url uri('https://jitpack.io') }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven {url uri('https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/')}
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-staggeredgrid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Netural:RemoteAppControl:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Here is my module `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `./gradlew assembleDebug` from your module dir?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this. There was a repository conflict. Removing `mavenCentral()` from `buildScript` of module `build.gradle` works like a wonder.