# Gradle build fails because of firebase-auth dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I have updated the firebase-auth dependency version but gradle build always fails. It was working fine for `16.0.1`

> Error `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2.`
>
> app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.pitchpls"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Project level gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv) question. Just had to uncheck the offline work in setting/gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try These steps:

- Open Module setting of the application
- Under Dependencies tab click on '+' symbol and add dependency manually a
- Click on apply.

Comment: Still not working. Even when i enable databinding and want to add firebase core or Glide dependency same error pops up

Comment: make sure that gradle Offline work in unchecked under File->Default setting

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0)

If you visit this link and scroll down to add dependency section, you will find out that gradle dependency version is **16.0.1 only**

Also, to avoid such errors, let Android Studio do automatically for you.

For this, in Android Studio, go to:
Tools-->Firebase (This will open a Firebase Assistant)

Now choose your category like Authentication,Analytics,Cloud Messaging,etc --> Click on "Setup your category" and proceed with the steps mentioned there. It will automatically add all the gradle files and generated JSON file.