# when i am using build app in android studio i get this error : Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting `gradle project sync failed` error in Android Studio.

[image]

Any help will be useful.

Thanks !!!!

Comment: It says "Unable to resolve dependency for..." in the bottom window. What are those dependencies? That's your issue.

Comment: Check this link
[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)

Comment: are you on a network with a proxy?

Comment: You can click on the open file or shoe details to see if you can resolve those dependencies. Else show us the error, and we can help.