# How to fix these library errors in this android project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

I have imported an old android project and I am trying to run it on my android studio but it is consistently giving an error with the name of the library and showing its directory. I am giving all the details of code and project below. I'll be very grateful if someone can help me run this project.

This is the Run Tasks error I am getting with this error in red 
"C:\Users\Hadis\AndroidStudioProjects\OnlineResortApp\app\libs\additional.jar"

I'm getting this stack trace:

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionLeafVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(AbstractFileCollection.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.classpath.impl.DefaultClasspathFingerprinter.fingerprint(DefaultClasspathFingerprinter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.TaskFingerprintUtil.fingerprintTaskFiles(TaskFingerprintUtil.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getBeforeExecutionState(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getExecutionStateChanges(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.getChangesSincePreviousExecution(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.transform.ArtifactTransformException: Failed to transform file 'additional.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformingArtifactVisitor.visitFile(TransformingArtifactVisitor.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet$SingletonFileResolvedVariant.visit(LocalFileDependencyBackedArtifactSet.java:171)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformCompletion.visit(TransformCompletion.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.CompositeResolvedArtifactSet$CompositeResult.visit(CompositeResolvedArtifactSet.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$500(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:231)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$200(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$1.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1147)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.execution.ExecutionException: Execution failed for IdentityTransform: C:\Users\Hadis\AndroidStudioProjects\OnlineResortApp\app\libs\additional.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$1(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:194)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:54)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4717)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3444)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2152)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2042)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4712)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.lambda$transform$1(TransformationStep.java:69)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationStep.transform(TransformationStep.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationChain.transform(TransformationChain.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationOperation.run(TransformationOperation.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$900(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:343)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Hadis\AndroidStudioProjects\OnlineResortApp\app\libs\additional.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.IdentityTransform.transform(IdentityTransform.kt:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformer.transform(DefaultTransformer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvoker$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvoker.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    ... 59 more
```

This is my build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.onlineresortapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
        targetCompatibility = '1.6'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additional.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
```

This is my Android Manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.onlineresortapp">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".BonVoyage"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/o"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Homepage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Destinations"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_destinations"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewYork"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_york"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Dubai"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dubai"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".London"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_london"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Malaysia"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_malaysia"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Paris"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_paris"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Venice"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_venice"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ThePlazaHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_the_plaza_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TheGreenwichHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_the_greenwich_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AceHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ace_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CorinthiaHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_corinthia_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LondonBridgeHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_london_bridge_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StGeorgeHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_st_george_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ArmaniHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_armani_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BayviewHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bayview_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LeMeridienHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_le_meridien_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GrandHyatt"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_grand_hyatt"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HotelSaintGermain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hotel_saint_germain"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LeBristolHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_le_bristol_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HiltonHotel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hilton_hotel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HotelIris"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hotel_iris"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Book"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_book"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Date_andDay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_date_and_day"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am expecting to run this project on the emulator but it is giving some of these errors which aren't allowing me to even check my app.

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\Hadis\AndroidStudioProjects\OnlineResortApp\app\libs\additional.jar` exist?

Comment: Yes it does. It is present in the libs folder.

Comment: And have you tried replacing `compile` with `implementation`? See: [What's the difference between implementation and compile in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44493378/295004)

Comment: Yes i did that too. Android studio replaces them itself as well but still facing the error.

Comment: The version of the support libraries that you’re using should be the same as the `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: Dear Edric!
Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I am also getting this warning

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv

Comment: Tried this as well but I am unable to run the project.

Comment: Will downsizing the version of my android studio can work?