# Gradle Sync Failed Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I got the error message

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0. Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app

I've unchecked Offline Work but still the same. 
This is my build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.crudmahasiswa"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Anyone please help me, i'm new on programming.. Thankyou

Comment: what else have your tried needs more info....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv/54298066#54298066